# How to sort by asc/desc value of a field?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a picture object with a rating.

```
type Picture @model {
  id: ID!
  file: S3Object!
  rating: Int
}
```

And I want to get the top 20 pictures that have the highest rating.
Do I need a custom resolver to do "sortBy"?
All my code is autogenerated by Amplify.

Comment: There have been a few requests from customers for a sort function in AppSync VTL resovlers; we'll +1 that request on our roadmap.